# Detect Click on image inside Html Editor?

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, dom-events, html-editor

I am working with the HTML Editor in ExtJS, and I want to detect a click inside the body of the editor and access the target element's attributes ? For instance, if the user clicked on an image, I want access the src attribute. So far I tried the following, but I can only detect a click but not which element was clicked on:

```
//Called after the editor has rendered
afterEditorRender : function( editor, eOpts )
{
        Ext.get(editor.iframeEl).on('click', function(e,t,a){console.log(e.target.id,t,a)})
...
```

In the "Source Edit" mode, following would be the only item in the editor:

```
<img src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/firefox/firefox-256.e2c1fc556816.jpg">​
```

[image]

Obviously, we can enter any number of attributes to this element when the image is inserted into the editor.

Comment: Could you add your HTML ?

Comment: @D.V. Edited with image.

Comment: Have you try by given "name" attribute to img tag and by "e.target.name" for getting target element ?

Comment: @Pepria can you please put your code in sencha fiddle for testing?